# Get same html Element without id using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am getting element with `event.target` or `event.srcElement`.

What information of event can I save to know exactly the previously element selected, without set a id?

If I close the page, how to get the same element?

Save all `parentNode` seems to be a very slow way to get the element again.

Is there a more efficient way?

The page will contain a fixed number of elements. But this page can not be changed, I could not include the id attribute. However, I would mark the last tag that was clicked when the user open the page again.

Comment: Just to be clear, `this` doesn't point to the element you need (in the scope of your event handler)?

Comment: When you close the page, and come back to it, obviously all of the elements will have been recreated and therefore the only way to accomplish this is some sort of unique id.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The most efficient way is almost certainly setting and `id`. Why the prohibition against the simplest solution?

Comment: @SoWeLie I added more information to the question

Comment: @Jordan the page can not be changed. And I need to know the last clicked element.

Comment: Do the element's have classes? You could create an xpath of sorts based on the element's class name.  You'd have to loop all the way up the parents to ensure everything is unique, and even then it's not 100% guaranteed.  Why can't you change the markup?

Comment: @SoWeLie System requirement, I can not change. Maybe event.offsetX can solve the problem. but how to get element by offsetX and Y? Is "offsetX and Y" reliable to get, regardless of scroll position?

Comment: No it is not, depending on your layout, and the size of the browser window that could change.  Not only that, I'm not sure if there is a way to get an element at a certain offset without looping through the entire DOM.  Either way, this is not a good solution.  Is the page dynamic at all? Could it change depending on certain data?  It sounds pretty unrealistic that you can't add an id somehow.

Comment: @SoWeLie The page is not dynamic, will never change. It only allows  reading.

Comment: If you can get `event.target` then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an interesting way.

To save element:

```
// Save node name and position with this
// el = elemento
var p = document.getElementsByTagName(nodeName);
for(var i=0; i<p.length; i++)
{
    if( el == p[i])
    {
        return i;
    }
}
```

To get:

```
// With nodeName saved and "position" i
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName(nodeName)[i];
```

Answer (score 3):

I need something similar and I am wondering what could go wrong with using css selectors (apart from older browser compatibility).

Something like:

```
$('body>div:nth-of-type(1)>div:nth-of-type(2)>ul>li:nth-of-type(3)')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ddimitrop/Qa8P2/

One could easily build such a selector following the path up to the body.

```
function structureSelector(element) {
  var tagName = element.tagName.toLowerCase();
  if (tagName == 'body') {
    return tagName;
  }
  var indexInParent = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(element.parentNode.childNodes, element);
  return structureSelector(element.parentNode)+'>'+tagName+':nth-child('+(indexInParent+1)+')';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ddimitrop/w9tbw/

Answer (score 1):

The best way, based on your requirements, is to generate some sort of xpath based on class names and if they don't exist, element names.  If you don't have an id that is the only way to get some sort of unique identifier for the element.  See my jsfiddle for an example.

```
var getNodeIdentifier = function(element) {
    return element.nodeName.toLowerCase() + "." + $(element).index();
};    

var current = element;
var xpath = getNodeIdentifier(this);

while (current.parentNode != null) {
    xpath = getNodeIdentifier(current.parentNode) + "/" + xpath;
    current = current.parentNode;
}

console.log(xpath);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qZMXN/29/

Please note, the only problem is if none of your elements have any classes, this will probably not work because if you have multiple elements at the same level with the same node type, there is no way to uniquely identify them.

Comment: The page will have multiple elements with the same nodes at the same level. :( How about offset position, the page will be used in only one  browser. I liked jsfiddle page +1

Comment: Hmm...yes you may be able to use the index within the parents.  Do you have the ability to include jquery in this page?

Comment: I will use the chrome. Forgot to mention that I do not know much about javascript, and do not know what is jquery, I'll read about it.

Comment: JQeury makes it easy to get at the ordinal of the node, I will update the jsfiddle.

Comment: I can not see the update on the link. Could You pass the new link?

Comment: I've updated the answer and the jsfiddle (new jsfiddle link).